# Android: AChartEngine vertical gradient on bars?

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I've been working with AChartEngine in Android and can't seem to find a way to put a vertical gradient on the bars of my stacked bar chart. Here is my code for the bars.

```
renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(1).setGradientEnabled(true);
renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(1).setGradientStart(0, Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));
renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(1).setGradientStop(45, Color.rgb(25, 25, 112));
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

I would like the gradient to go from left to right, not bottom to top. Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The gradient in AChartEngine is based on displayed data values. The values in your bar chart raise from bottom to top, so the gradient is displayed on the same direction.

Comment: Hmm ok...is there any way to use an image as the paint for the bars? That way I could make an image that had a left-right gradient and set it as the background image for the bars

Comment: No, there isn't such thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I require such a gradient. Do you know if AFreeChart supports stacked bar charts? I've seen left-right gradients on that software. Thanks for your replies by the way!